# Docker doesn't seem to be mapping ports

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hugo

I'm working with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io)

Trying to run inside a Docker container to allow people to easily manage content.

My first task is to get Hugo running and people able to view the site locally.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache go bash git openssh && \
    mkdir -p /aws && \
    apk -Uuv add groff less python py-pip && \
    pip install awscli && \
    apk --purge -v del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /go/src /go/bin && chmod -R 777 /go

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH

RUN go get -v github.com/spf13/hugo

RUN git clone http://mygitrepo.com /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 1313

ENTRYPOINT ["hugo","server"]
```

I'm checking out the site repo then running Hugo - `hugo server`

I'm then running this container via:

```
docker run -d -p 1313:1313 --name app app
```

Which reports everything is starting OK however when I try to browse locally on `localhost:1313` I see nothing.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE

`docker ps` gives me:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9e1f12849044        app                "hugo server"       16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:1313->1313/tcp   app
```

And `docker logs 9e1` gives me:

```
Started building sites ...
Built site for language en:
0 draft content
0 future content
0 expired content
25 pages created
0 non-page files copied
0 paginator pages created
0 tags created
0 categories created
total in 64 ms
Watching for changes in /ltec/{data,content,layouts,static,themes}
Serving pages from memory
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)
Press Ctrl+C to stop
```

Comment: Can you check if the process is running on that port?

Comment: Added `docker ps` output

Comment: Did you read this? It might help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: You shouldn't clone your codebase in the dockerfile. If you want people to see the website why can't they clone the repo in local and add à docker-compose to mount the codebase into the container ?

Comment: @GouravChawla I'm already mapping the port via `-p` I don't see what else this documentation offers?

Comment: @Sylwit I understand this isn't ideal but the users are non-technical so I'm trying to simplify the process

Comment: Try this, `docker exec -ti #container-id bash` to enter your container then `curl http://localhost:1313` . Does it return something ? Also for your comment, user need to have docker installed so why don't you package a running image with copying your code and give them the command to start a container with pulling your image

Comment: curl returns the correct HTTP response

Comment: What is your docker host OS?

Comment: Mac OSX. Running Docker 1.12.1-beta26.1 (build: 12100)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but following this tutorial http://ahmedalani.com/post/so-recursive-it-hurts/, says about to use the param **--bind** from **hugo server** command.

Adding that param mentioned, and the ip **0.0.0.0** we have **--bind=0.0.0.0**

It works to me, I think this is a natural behavior from every container taking a **localhost** for self scope, but if you bind with 0.0.0.0 takes a visible scope to the main host.

Comment: `docker run --name "my-hugo" --rm -p 127.0.0.1:1313:1313 -v $(pwd):/src jojomi/hugo hugo --bind=0.0.0.0` worked for me. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Delete `EXPOSE 1313` in your Dockerfile. [Dockerfile reference.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/expose)

Comment: sure, let me know :-)

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately. What's your thinking behind removing the `EXPOSE` command?

Comment: Well, I thought some kind of port conflict. I have never used the EXPOSE command so far. I am sorry that it didn't help. :-(

Comment: So the container would listen on that port at runtime.

Comment: OK, I always only used the `-p` flag. May be the port 1313 is already used by another program? May be you can try to expose any other port? For example: `-p 19098:1313`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Docker is actually running in a VM. You need to navigate to the docker-machine ip instead of localhost.

`curl $(docker-machine ip):1313`

Comment: You might want to clarify that this is only the case when using "Docker Toolbox" on OSX and Windows

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help as I'm using Docker for Mac, not the toolbox. This runs natively, not in a VM as far as I'm aware - http://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac